# Why am I not seeing any firephp output?

Tags: php, firephp

I am trying to get firephp to work.  It was working as of last week and I don't know when
exactly it stopped working or what I changed.

I am now trying to do a simple firephp hello world.

```
<?php
require_once('FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
ob_start();
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
$firephp->log('Hello', 'World');

require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
$var='test';
fb($var);
FB::send($var);

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

There is no result in the firebug console window and no error messages I can find.

FireFox 5.0

FireBug 1.8.0

PHP 5.3.1

Firebug console and net panels are enabled.  FirePHP is enabled.

In the net panel under the get request, I do not see any X-wf- headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FirePHP Extension now works again with Firebug 1.8: http://www.firephp.org/HQ/FinalRelease.htm

Explanation of what happened: http://www.christophdorn.com/Blog/2011/08/03/firephp-and-firebug-1-8/

Answer (score 6):

Firebug has to have the Net panel enabled.

EDIT: Just press f12, click on the Net and if it says enable, click on enable :)

Comment: This was driving me crazy, maybe if I had have just stopped and thought about it, I would've realised. Thanks for pointing out the obvious :)

Comment: The obvious is usually the hardest to notice and easiest to destroy ones mojo :)

Answer (score 4):

This one is ridiculous but I just wasted 30 mins, make sure you have your output set on 'All' and not 'Errors' or something like that in the firePHP console.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a knowned issue using the latest Firebug version 1.8 and Firefox 5:
http://groups.google.com/group/firephp-dev/browse_thread/thread/aa8ca7877f4f2d82?pli=1

Downgrading to version 1.7.3 solved the problem for me.
http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.7/firebug-1.7.3.xpi

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ob_end_flush()` for any output to get sent to the browser.

Comment: added to the test script but no change :(

Comment: It was worth a shot. I've never used FirePHP, but looking at the site, it seems you can log in the form `FB::log('Log message');`. Have you tried this syntax?

Comment: Personally, this is where I would start debugging FirePHP. The code looks a little hairy and not well commented in places, but it seems you're calling it correctly, so I would take that as a next step.

Answer (score 0):

As I was led here by a google result motivated by the same problem I would like to add some perspective for posterity.

While testing in local environment on any of the new Windows OSs (Windwos 7 and above) you should check if your file is **blocked** .

That's right: in my case require_once didnt throw any fatal errors which it should if it couldnt find the file - so sth. had to be wrong with the file.

On Linux you would check permissions, on windows you need to check the file properties and see if the file is being blocked.

If it is and you have admin privileges, you can unblock it then and there.